# How can i use For Loop correctly for multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

I have the following loop below:

```
With Sheets("Sheet Name")
    For i = 2 To 26
        .Cells(11, i).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F8:F" & n), Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Chr(64 + i) & "8"), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AC8:AC" & n), "S")
        .Cells(12, i).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F8:F" & n), Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Chr(64 + i) & "8"), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AC8:AC" & n), "YS")            
    Next i
End With
```

The last condition at the end of each line changes by a string i.e. "S", "YS". I want to avoid having to use 1 line for each "S" and "YS" and so on i.e. there will be many lines for each criteria. I also then want to add another for loop that deals with the rows

Comment: What do you mean by **_...need to find a way to put this into 1 line..._**?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity, will update above @FDavidov

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
codes = Array("S", "YS")
For i = 2 To 26
    For j = 0 to UBound(codes)
        Sheets("Sheet Name").Cells(11+j, i).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F8:F" & n), Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Chr(64 + i) & "8"), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AC8:AC" & n), codes(j))
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Works Perfectly! I knew there must be a way, Need to study Arrays more!

Answer (score -1):

The next step in my long list of issues and improvements was to simulate this but for a SUMIFS, as i was looking at cost data.

Please see below and i hope others can benefit from this and perhaps improve!

```
With Sheets("Operations Schedules -Summary")
    For i = 2 To 26
        For j = 0 To UBound(codes)
            .Cells(37 + j, i).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AD8:AD" & n), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F8:F" & n), Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Chr(64 + i) & "8"), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AC8:AC" & n), codes(j))
        Next j
    Next i
End With
```

Some basic syntax of SUMIFS:

- The first part is to specify the sum range
- The Second part(s) is to specify the criteria range, and then the critera
- This goes on for 197 criterias i believe!

For any Novices looking at the various qualifications of variables above:

- i,j, and n are variables of type long. n is used  to count (dynamically), the number of rows in the target dataset